# Azure SQL connect from Web Application

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, publish

I have some trouble to connect my application (deployed to an Azure Web Site)
to a *SQL Azure DB*.
I get an error on the **connection.Open()**
The connection string is right. (I can connect from SQL Studio)
Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would look at a couple of things.

1. is your web site in the same region as your DB? If not, I would make them be in the same region if only for the improvement of speed..
2. is there a security block on your DB that is only allowing access from certain IP addresses?  If so you have to allow for the web site to have access to the DB.

Comment: Thanks, yes they re in the same region. How can I check the second option?

Comment: Here's how to configure your DB firewall http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx